# I have the following issue when i start the server. No mapping found for HTTP request with URL

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

How to solve this. i have index.jsp but it does not open that jsp what can i do?

ERROR is:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/RoomController/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SpringServiceJsonSample</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.Room" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.Room.Model.RoomMembers</value>
        <value>com.Room.Model.MemberInOut</value>
        <value>com.Room.Model.RoomDetails</value>

    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

controller class is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Room/")
public class RoomController {

@Autowired
RoomDao roomDao;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public String getAllUsers() {
    String users="hello welcome ";
    return users;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/ViewMember",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<RoomMembers> getRoomMembers() {
    List<RoomMembers> roomMemberList= new ArrayList<RoomMembers>();
    roomMemberList=roomDao.listMember();
    return roomMemberList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping configuration is incorrect. You can map your controller with URI using `@RequestMapping` by specifying `value` attribute in it as follows:

> @RequestMapping(value="")

So when you define your controller as mentioned in question, you can access it by `/Room/` and not with **/RoomController**.

Comment: i was remove /Room/ means it was download a json file

Comment: i want to open index.jsp. so what are the changes i want to do

Comment: If you want to access index.jsp, then just use `@Controller` annotation with one method defined to provide view name as a return value.

Answer (score 0):

There should be method in your controller with default mapping of your '/RoomController' and which return the index.jsp as the view part as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String displayGui(ModelMap model) {
        // Add value to model
        model.addAttribute(...);
        model.addAttribute(...);

        //return to view index.jsp
        return "index";
}
```

So when you hit http://yourIP:port/RoomController, then the above displayGui method will be invoked and will return the index.jsp/